# Как соединить несколько const array в один в виде константы в Delphi?

Tags: массивы, delphi, const, syntax

Как несколько const array соединить в один в виде константы?

Пример, того что мне нужно:

```
const   
    A1: array [0..1] of string = ( 'go' );
    A2: array [0..2] of string = ( 'o','i','j' );

    A3: array [0..1] of string = ( 'xxx','yy' );
    A4: array [0..1] of string = ( '111','222' );


    All: array of array = (A1,A2,A3,A4);
```

Comment: Так - не получится. Только явно:     const All: array[0..3,0..2]  of string = (('a','b','c'), ('aa','ba','ca'), ('ab','bb','cb'),('ac','bc','cc'));   Ну, либо объявлять переменную нужного массива и собирать при старте.